# Strip html tags except <b> using regex c#

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing

I wanted to strip all the html but preserve `<b>` tags using regex. Is there a better way to do instead of

1. Replace `<b>` with a non html tag like $b$
2. Remove all html tags using `<[^>]*>`
3. Replace $b$ with `<b>`

Comment: Regex is not the best thing to be parsing html/xml with. Look into [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx), you can use XPath to parse through it's elements and achieve your goal much easier.

Comment: [Obligatory regex with HTML SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Jean, while regex is not ideal for nested constructs, if the OP doesn't care about nesting (and only cares about `<b>` tags regardless of nesting level) then regexes will work just fine.  (also most HTML -- especially HTML5 html -- is not *valid* XML.  for example, `<br>` is perfectly legal but invalid xml)

Comment: Yes. I don't have about any other constructs. I just want to strip all except b tags them. I am only doing this a small html snippet (1000 characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is one approach that will only permit opening and closing `b` tags.  Any other tags are removed.

```
var teststring = "Test <b>test</b> lorem <i>ipsum</i>";
var pattern = @"(?!</?b>)<.*?>"; // assuming open and closing tags are retained
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace
       (teststring,
         pattern,
         String.Empty,
         RegexOptions.Multiline));
```

Outputs: `Test <b>test</b> lorem ipsum`

Comment: Thanks Drf. Curious will yours be faster execution wise compared to mine? Also i want the html tags stripped not encode it.

Comment: I updated the code based on your comment.  It is difficult to answer the performance question for [a number of reasons](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/), but (with that disclaimer) I would not expect this approach to be any faster for a single tag. It could, however, simplify adding other tags. A potential (and likely minor) issue with your approach is that if the input happens to contain the text `$b$`, it will be incorrectly translated to `<b>`.